# Is it possible that an query for one element is causing .CursorWindowAllocationException?

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I just got this error on my crashlytics:

> Non-fatal Exception: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 4194304 bytes failed.
> at android.database.CursorWindow.(CursorWindow.java:136)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:315)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:155)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:149)

But my query is retriving just one element

```
SELECT *
FROM Monitoring M
JOIN FhirPackage F ON M.id = F.monitoringId
WHERE uploadedToDeviceCentral = 0
    AND F.readyToUpload = 1
    AND M.userId = :userId
    AND M.organizationId = :orgId
ORDER BY startTimestamp LIMIT 1
```

This table can store a lot of data, like millions, but I'm just searching for one row. Even in this situation, it is possible that this is causing the memory leak? There is something I can do about it?

Comment: How many columns are in `Monitoring` and `FhirPackage`? Are any of them potentially large (e.g., you stored images in a `BLOB` column`)?

Comment: 31 columns and I'm just storing string, long, float, double and boolean. I'm not saving a lot of data in this table tho, but FhirPackage has tons of data in a few columns (11). I'm saving a big string for each row on FhirPackage (size 52802), but I'm not using it on where clause of that query

Answer (score 1):

> I'm saving a big string for each row on FhirPackage (size 52802), but I'm not using it on where clause of that query

You are using `SELECT *`, and you are joining on `FhirPackage`. So, you are returning that big string (along with all other columns on the joined tables), and that may be contributing to your problem.

Try limiting the `SELECT` column list to just the columns you need, from the table(s) that contain them.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it!! I thought that just not using it on where clause was safe